# Remove top space from website

Tags: css

I want to remove the **top space** on [this](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/bankalhabib/) website. I have tried using `firebug` but I am unable to find where the top space is coming from.

Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `html, body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: Its already applied there.

Comment: remove `<hr style="height:10px;background-color:#3E6A56;">`

Answer (score 2):

You need not to remove `hr` from page. Just add

```
<hr style="height:10px;background-color:#3E6A56;margin: 0px;">
```

Possibly `hr` tag has margin defined in somewhere your css which is causing extra space.

Comment: So the margin is coming from the <hr> tag?

Comment: Possibly.. Give a try.

Answer (score -1):

You have two ways to achieve it, 
First one is to completely remove the following HR tag from your html.

```
<hr style="height:10px;background-color:#3E6A56;margin: 0px;">
```

Or you can add a font-size of 0px, so as to hide it, as shown below.

```
<hr style="height:10px;background-color:#3E6A56;font-size: 0;">
```